# Rails how change google maps marker?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-maps, google-maps-markers

hello I would change the marker in a map , i use rails and i wrote this javascript function for set marker so if i change the marker with   url: "icona.png" where icona.png is locate in the same folder of the resource promotions no show me the marker on map. Why? how change the default market there is another method?

```
      function setMarkers(map, locations) {
      // Add markers to the map

      // Marker sizes are expressed as a Size of X,Y
      // where the origin of the image (0,0) is located
      // in the top left of the image.

      // Origins, anchor positions and coordinates of the marker
      // increase in the X direction to the right and in
      // the Y direction down.
      var image = {
          url: "icona.png",
          // This marker is 20 pixels wide by 32 pixels tall.
          size: new google.maps.Size(20, 32),
          // The origin for this image is 0,0.
          origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
          // The anchor for this image is the base of the flagpole at 0,32.
          anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
      };
      var shadow = {
          url: "icona.png",
          // The shadow image is larger in the horizontal dimension
          // while the position and offset are the same as for the main image.
          size: new google.maps.Size(37, 32),
          origin: new google.maps.Point(0,0),
          anchor: new google.maps.Point(0, 32)
      };
      // Shapes define the clickable region of the icon.
      // The type defines an HTML &lt;area&gt; element 'poly' which
      // traces out a polygon as a series of X,Y points. The final
      // coordinate closes the poly by connecting to the first
      // coordinate.
      var shape = {
          coord: [1, 1, 1, 20, 18, 20, 18 , 1],
          type: 'poly'
      };
```

Answer (score 3):

Try to put javascript in **app/assets/javascripts/** and marker in **app/assets/images/** folder. Then route to image: **"/assets/marker.png"**

You can read more there http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html